# How would I connect very fine wire (0.005") to a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Let's say I have very fine gauge wire of 0.005" (0.127 mm) diameter.

This wire is completely exposed (i.e. no insulation). What are available methods for terminating this to a PCB? Searching through Digikey and Mouser, the smallest gauge terminal blocks I could find were only 30AWG.

I'm thinking that there must be some type of PCB 'post' in which I could wrap the wire around to make the termination. I'm thinking something like this exists, but my searches yield no results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Google wire bonding. But i think it's for even thinner wires

Comment: 36 awg blocks should exist though.

Comment: @Passerby I was unable to filter for 36 awg on digikey or mouser. The smallest diameter gauge i could find was 30awg.

Comment: Probably not standard sizes. Look at manufacturer websites for custom parts? If this is one off, you'd be better off just soldering I guess.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're using this thin wire for?  Perhaps there are some application specific recommendations we could make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reason you can't use a standard header pin, or a wire wrap pin, wrap it around then solder.

Alternatively, a copper landing/square/point can be used.

Often small gauge wire is soldered to test points for debugging or hacking purposes, and that's essentially what you'd be doing.

Comment: Regarding the wire wrap option, do you know if there are any 'screw top' variations? I'm think it would be good to wrap it around a pin, and then screw down (maybe a nut on the otherside) such that the wire is firmly held? Essentially, just an alternative to soldering.

Comment: @teague that's not what a wire wrap post is. That a screw terminal. Sure, you could do just that, but the thinness of the wire may cause it to fail to grab or damage the wire causing it to fail. The thinner the wire the less mechanically strong it will be.

Comment: @Teague you should [look into](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_wrap) (see paragraph 3) wire wrapping. It creates a cold weld between the corners of the post and the wire; this bond is as strong as soldering when correctly done.

Answer (score 2):

0.127 millimeter isn't really all that unhandleable. Simply solder it on – a wire that small isn't something that you can exert reasonable force on, anyway, so any "plugging" where the wire might be exposed to mechanical forces isn't a good idea.

If you really needs something de- and reattachable: get a thicker wire (which will make handling much easier), get something like a flat/ribbon cable (if it's multiple leads).